# Check whether geospatial Point in bounding rectangle

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, geospatial, spatial

I have the coordinates that represents bounding rectangle on the earth:

Upper Left Corner Latitude

Upper Left Corner Longitude

Lower Right Corner Latitude

Lower Right Corner Longitude

I need to write the function that determines whether the given point with lat long coordinates hit the bounding rectangle.

Is there any way to do it ?
I didn't find functions in sql server to do it. All functions work with lines and polygons, but I have only bounds, not the complete polygon or line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a polygon of your four points, and call `STWithin` against your geometry point, or `STIntersects` against a geography

ie: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929207.aspx

```
 declare @area geography, @point geography
 select @area = geography :: STGeomFromText('polygon((10 10, 20 10, 20 20, 10 20, 10 10))', 4326)
 select @point = geography :: STGeomFromText('point(15 15)', 4326)
 select @area.STIntersects(@point)

 select @point = geography :: STGeomFromText('point(5 5)', 4326)
 select @area.STIntersects(@point)
```

Comment: Will it be a valid rectangle on the Earth if I will calculate low left and upper right corners with simple calculations from the existing points and the use them to construct the polygon ?

Comment: No - that would be a line . You need to interpret the other two points (ie: (Upper Left Latitude, Lower Right Longitude), (Upper Left Longitude, Lower Right Latitude)

Comment: @Madman I beg to differ http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933991(v=sql.100)

Comment: @Madman Ah, that's only for geometrys on Sql 2008 - STIntersects should do the same for geographys, I think

Comment: @Madman I've revised the answer to show an example with a geography

Comment: What if the four points are the north pole, south pole, and two points opposite each other on the equator? Which hemisphere is "in" and which is "out" of the "rectangle"? Connected points on a sphere do not form a polygon, they divide the spherical space into two, each of which has a right to call itself inside or outside without further information.

Comment: @Spacedman A SQL 2008 geography element must be sized less than a hemisphere. In SQL 2012, the order the points are specified defines "inside" and "outside"